# How to get file name of image / video / audio in slide for Keynote with Applescript

Tags: applescript, keynote

I'm trying to get the file name of either an image, video or audio that will be placed on a slide in a Keynote presentation. I saw the iWork item has a property called file name. However, I don't know how to find the object in the slide and get its file name.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Since Applescript works with hierarchy, you just need access de iWork item that belongs the current slide that belongs the current document.

```
set filenameVideo to get the file name of the iWork item of the current slide of the front document
```